# json and cors with akka http

Tags: json, scala, akka-http

I have a post message. I use akka-http.
And I have to call this route from an another server.

So I have to add cors with  HttpOriginRange.* with ch.megard.akka.http.cors.CorsDirectives.

The answer is a json. 
And I want to have a ContentType application/json

How can I do that?

Here is my route code :

```
settings = CorsSettings.defaultSettings.copy(allowGenericHttpRequests = true, allowCredentials = false, allowedOrigins = HttpOriginRange.*)
 val route: Route =
        handleRejections(CorsDirectives.corsRejectionHandler) {
            cors(settings) {
                handleRejections(RejectionHandler.default) {
                    post {
                        authenticated(doAuthApp) { app =>
                            complete("success")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried this :

```
val route: Route =

    handleRejections(CorsDirectives.corsRejectionHandler) {
        cors(WebServer.settings) {
            handleRejections(RejectionHandler.default) {
                 (decodeRequest & encodeResponse) {
                     mapResponseEntity(_.withContentType(ContentTypes.`application/json`)) {
                post {
                    authenticated(doAuthApp) { app =>
                        complete("success")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

If I do that I have an error : Unexpected 's'

Could you help me please?

Comment: I think posting the complete error message would help

Comment: This is the uniq message i have in return with postman . Nothing on my logs sadly :(

Comment: HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`), "success".getBytes)) ?

Comment: Gaston , with your answer i have this error : 
expression of type HttpResponse doesn t conform to expected type server.Route

Comment: I have a post endpoint with  this code and works                                ' **complete{   
  HttpResponse(entity =    HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.application/json), "success".getBytes))  }**

Comment: Ok , i forgot the complete {} ... But after that i have stil the same error : 
Unexpected 's'  in postman

With chrome debugger i have the same error but "more complete " : 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
   at fromJson (angular.js:1345)

Comment: it looks like you are just sending back the string "success", that isn't valid json

Comment: thansk com_dog, you were right :) 
it works now

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
var  settings = CorsSettings.defaultSettings.copy(allowGenericHttpRequests = true, allowCredentials = false, allowedOrigins = HttpOriginRange.*)

val route =
pathPrefix("testEndpoint") {
  handleRejections(CorsDirectives.corsRejectionHandler) {
    cors(settings) {
      handleRejections(RejectionHandler.default) {
        post {
          entity(as[String]) {
            app =>
              complete("success")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```